# LEFT JOIN with a dataset that might or might not exist

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to JOIN a Master Dataset, via a left join with 2 other Datasets, all of them have the same Key field. So nothing special there.
One of those secondary Datasets is the result of another Query and therefor might or might not exist. Obviously my JOIN statement fails when this table doesn't exist.

Below a really simplified version of the code, the JOIN is used to exclude rows from the table_a that exist in table b or c (if they exist).

```
SELECT                  a.id, a.name
FROM                    table_a  a
LEFT JOIN               table_b  b
 ON                     a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN               table c  c
ON                      a.id = c.id
WHERE                   b.id IS NULL
 AND                    c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Presumably how to write a query that automagically does not fail if one of its tables does not exist. That said: _"One of those secondary Datasets is the result of another Query and therefor might or might not exist."_ Some explanation of this would help. It sounds vague and possibly like a design smell.

Comment: Okay makes sense, I'll elaborate :

We receive on a daily base a file on our SFTP server, our BI Platform, picks up this file and turns it into a DAILY dataset, however if there is no file that day, there will also be no DAILY dataset.

The SQL script I'm trying to build, will create and maintain a HISTORY table, and adding the rows from the DAILY dataset, that don't exist in the HISTORY dataset, yet. And updating the the rows that exist in both datasets.

Comment: So my idea was doing this via a join, taking the HISTORY Dataset, removing the records that are in the DAILY dataset and then "appending" the DAILY to the skimmed HISTORY via a UNION step.

Comment: You need to create an sql stored procedure or sql script or a script in a programming language that can connect to mysql to check if your daily table exists. If it does not, then the script would execute a different query that does not try to join on the daily table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question well, but I think that you should better do:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name
FROM table_a a
WHERE a.id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table_b)
AND a.id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table_c)
```

Any query optimizer should have the exact same performance with this request, and I find it much more readable.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, I agree that's and easier to read syntax, however the problem when table_c doesn't exist that day, will still result in a "Table does not exist" error